# htaccess 301 redirect in Magento 2

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have trouble to get the 301 redirects working.
My goal is it to redirect domain one with sub directory to domain two without sub directory but with all the attributes.
FA. `http://example.com/foo/bar` -> `http://example.org/bar`

I've tried different approaches. The latest is

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/foo/(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://example.org/%1 [R=302,NC]
```

The full .htaccess looks like this:

```
############################################
## overrides deployment configuration mode value
## use command bin/magento deploy:mode:set to switch modes
#   SetEnv MAGE_MODE developer
############################################
## uncomment these lines for CGI mode
## make sure to specify the correct cgi php binary file name
## it might be /cgi-bin/php-cgi
#    Action php5-cgi /cgi-bin/php5-cgi
#    AddHandler php5-cgi .php
############################################
## GoDaddy specific options
#   Options -MultiViews
## you might also need to add this line to php.ini
##     cgi.fix_pathinfo = 1
## if it still doesn't work, rename php.ini to php5.ini
############################################
## this line is specific for 1and1 hosting
    #AddType x-mapp-php5 .php
    #AddHandler x-mapp-php5 .php
############################################
## default index file
    DirectoryIndex index.php
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
############################################
## adjust memory limit
    php_value memory_limit 756M
    php_value max_execution_time 18000
############################################
## disable automatic session start
## before autoload was initialized
    php_flag session.auto_start off
############################################
## enable resulting html compression
    #php_flag zlib.output_compression on
###########################################
## disable user agent verification to not break multiple image upload
    php_flag suhosin.session.cryptua off
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_php7.c>
############################################
## adjust memory limit
    php_value memory_limit 756M
    php_value max_execution_time 18000
############################################
## disable automatic session start
## before autoload was initialized
    php_flag session.auto_start off
############################################
## enable resulting html compression
    #php_flag zlib.output_compression on
###########################################
## disable user agent verification to not break multiple image upload
    php_flag suhosin.session.cryptua off
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_security.c>
###########################################
## disable POST processing to not break multiple image upload
    SecFilterEngine Off
    SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
############################################
## enable apache served files compression
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#gzip
    # Insert filter on all content
    ###SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
    # Insert filter on selected content types only
    #AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/css text/javascript application/javascript application/x-javascript application/json image/svg+xml
    # Netscape 4.x has some problems...
    #BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
    # Netscape 4.06-4.08 have some more problems
    #BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
    # MSIE masquerades as Netscape, but it is fine
    #BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
    # Don't compress images
    #SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$ no-gzip dont-vary
    # Make sure proxies don't deliver the wrong content
    #Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
############################################
## make HTTPS env vars available for CGI mode
    SSLOptions StdEnvVars
</IfModule>
############################################
## workaround for Apache 2.4.6 CentOS build when working via ProxyPassMatch with HHVM (or any other)
## Please, set it on virtual host configuration level
##    SetEnvIf Authorization "(.*)" HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1
############################################
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
############################################
## enable rewrites
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on
############################################
## you can put here your magento root folder
## path relative to web root
    #RewriteBase /magento/
############################################
## workaround for HTTP authorization
## in CGI environment
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
############################################
## TRACE and TRACK HTTP methods disabled to prevent XSS attacks
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^TRAC[EK]
    RewriteRule .* - [L,R=405]
############################################
## redirect for mobile user agents
    #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mobiledirectoryhere/.*$
    #RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|ipad|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile" [NC]
    #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /mobiledirectoryhere/ [L,R=302]
############################################
## never rewrite for existing files, directories and links
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
############################################
## rewrite everything else to index.php

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/shop/(.*)$
    RewriteRule ^(.*) https://example.org/%1 [R=302,NC]
    RewriteRule .* index.php [L]

</IfModule>
############################################
## Prevent character encoding issues from server overrides
## If you still have problems, use the second line instead
    AddDefaultCharset Off
    #AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
    AddType 'text/html; charset=UTF-8' html
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
############################################
## Add default Expires header
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#expires
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType text/html A0
    ExpiresByType text/plain A0
</IfModule>
###########################################
## Deny access to root files to hide sensitive application information
    RedirectMatch 403 /\.git
    <Files composer.json>
        <IfVersion < 2.4>
            order allow,deny
            deny from all
        </IfVersion>
        <IfVersion >= 2.4>
            Require all denied
        </IfVersion>
    </Files>
    <Files composer.lock>
        <IfVersion < 2.4>
            order allow,deny
            deny from all
        </IfVersion>
        <IfVersion >= 2.4>
            Require all denied
        </IfVersion>
    </Files>
    <Files .gitignore>
        <IfVersion < 2.4>
            order allow,deny
            deny from all
        </IfVersion>
        <IfVersion >= 2.4>
            Require all denied
        </IfVersion>
    </Files>
    <Files .htaccess>
        <IfVersion < 2.4>
            order allow,deny
            deny from all
        </IfVersion>
        <IfVersion >= 2.4>
            Require all denied
        </IfVersion>
    </Files>
    <Files .htaccess.sample>
        <IfVersion < 2.4>
            order allow,deny
            deny from all
        </IfVersion>
        <IfVersion >= 2.4>
            Require all denied
        </IfVersion>
    </Files>
    <Files .php_cs.dist>
        <IfVersion < 2.4>
            order allow,deny
            deny from all
        </IfVersion>
        <IfVersion >= 2.4>
            Require all denied
        </IfVersion>
    </Files>
    <Files .travis.yml>
        <IfVersion < 2.4>
            order allow,deny
            deny from all
        </IfVersion>
        <IfVersion >= 2.4>
            Require all denied
        </IfVersion>
    </Files>
    <Files CHANGELOG.md>
        <IfVersion < 2.4>
            order allow,deny
            deny from all
        </IfVersion>
        <IfVersion >= 2.4>
            Require all denied
        </IfVersion>
    </Files>
    <Files COPYING.txt>
        <IfVersion < 2.4>
            order allow,deny
            deny from all
        </IfVersion>
        <IfVersion >= 2.4>
            Require all denied
        </IfVersion>
    </Files>
    <Files Gruntfile.js>
        <IfVersion < 2.4>
            order allow,deny
            deny from all
        </IfVersion>
        <IfVersion >= 2.4>
            Require all denied
        </IfVersion>
    </Files>
    <Files LICENSE.txt>
        <IfVersion < 2.4>
            order allow,deny
            deny from all
        </IfVersion>
        <IfVersion >= 2.4>
            Require all denied
        </IfVersion>
    </Files>
    <Files LICENSE_AFL.txt>
        <IfVersion < 2.4>
            order allow,deny
            deny from all
        </IfVersion>
        <IfVersion >= 2.4>
            Require all denied
        </IfVersion>
    </Files>
    <Files nginx.conf.sample>
        <IfVersion < 2.4>
            order allow,deny
            deny from all
        </IfVersion>
        <IfVersion >= 2.4>
            Require all denied
        </IfVersion>
    </Files>
    <Files package.json>
        <IfVersion < 2.4>
            order allow,deny
            deny from all
        </IfVersion>
        <IfVersion >= 2.4>
            Require all denied
        </IfVersion>
    </Files>
    <Files php.ini.sample>
        <IfVersion < 2.4>
            order allow,deny
            deny from all
        </IfVersion>
        <IfVersion >= 2.4>
            Require all denied
        </IfVersion>
    </Files>
    <Files README.md>
        <IfVersion < 2.4>
            order allow,deny
            deny from all
        </IfVersion>
        <IfVersion >= 2.4>
            Require all denied
        </IfVersion>
    </Files>
    <Files auth.json>
        <IfVersion < 2.4>
            order allow,deny
            deny from all
        </IfVersion>
        <IfVersion >= 2.4>
            Require all denied
        </IfVersion>
    </Files>
    <Files magento_umask>
        <IfVersion < 2.4>
            order allow,deny
            deny from all
        </IfVersion>
        <IfVersion >= 2.4>
            Require all denied
        </IfVersion>
    </Files>
# For 404s and 403s that aren't handled by the application, show plain 404 response
ErrorDocument 404 /pub/errors/404.php
ErrorDocument 403 /pub/errors/404.php
################################
## If running in cluster environment, uncomment this
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#etags
    #FileETag none
# ######################################################################
# # INTERNET EXPLORER                                                  #
# ######################################################################
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# | Document modes                                                     |
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Force Internet Explorer 8/9/10 to render pages in the highest mode
# available in the various cases when it may not.
#
# https://hsivonen.fi/doctype/#ie8
#
# (!) Starting with Internet Explorer 11, document modes are deprecated.
# If your business still relies on older web apps and services that were
# designed for older versions of Internet Explorer, you might want to
# consider enabling `Enterprise Mode` throughout your company.
#
# https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/bg182625.aspx#docmode
# http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2014/04/02/stay-up-to-date-with-enterprise-mode-for-internet-explorer-11.aspx
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set X-UA-Compatible "IE=edge"
    # `mod_headers` cannot match based on the content-type, however,
    # the `X-UA-Compatible` response header should be send only for
    # HTML documents and not for the other resources.
    <FilesMatch "\.(appcache|atom|bbaw|bmp|crx|css|cur|eot|f4[abpv]|flv|geojson|gif|htc|ico|jpe?g|js|json(ld)?|m4[av]|manifest|map|mp4|oex|og[agv]|opus|otf|pdf|png|rdf|rss|safariextz|svgz?|swf|topojson|tt[cf]|txt|vcard|vcf|vtt|webapp|web[mp]|webmanifest|woff2?|xloc|xml|xpi)$">
        Header unset X-UA-Compatible
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

I assume that some of the other rewrite rules are getting "accepted" so that the desired rule gets kind of bypassed

Answer (score 0):

You can test this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^foo/(.*)$ https://example.org/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Is works for me.